# How can I scale a sigmoid curve to fit the criteria I would like

Tags: functions, curves

Is there a way I can make a scaled sigmoid function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) \to -1$ (or as close to it as possible) and $f(n) \to 1$ (or as close to it as possible), for whatever $n$ I choose?

Comment: What do you mean by "scaled sigmoid function"? I.e., (1) what functions are you allowed to use and (2) what kinds of modifications to the function are you allowed to make?

Comment: I just want some sort of smooth, S-shaped function, that maps $x \epsilon [0, n] \to [-1, +1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(0) \to -1$ ? Do you mean $\lim_{x \to 0 }f(x) = -1$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry, my mathematical notation knowledge isn't too advanced. That's exactly what I meant by "or as close to -1 as possible).

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your requirements are, but one thing you could try, is
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{1+ \exp \left( -kx + \frac{b}{2} \right)} -1
$$
and then mess around with the coefficients $k$ and $b$. Here's a visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kec9l2rkgl. In this case, the coefficient $b$ could be something like the $n$ you were talking about.

Comment: @MattiP. This is very close to what I am looking at, but is there anyway to sort of "stretch out" the S-shape proportionally to the value of $b$? For example, if $b=100$? I want the vast majority of $x$-values from $0$ to $b$ to output as something in between -1 and +1, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with 5xum, I will give another solution, using the sigmoid function.
The function that I would present is
$$
f(x) = 2\left(1+\exp\left\{ -\ln(40~000) \frac{x-n}{n} + \ln(0.005) \right\} \right)^{-1} +1 
$$
Here is a visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ah3qgjbim

Notice that I have determined the coefficients $\ln (40~000)$ and $\ln (0.005)$ by setting certain values for $f(0)$ and $f(n)$. They can be replaced by $\ln(\text{a large number})$ and $\ln(\text{a small but positive number})$.

Comment: I understand that there are infinitely many curves fitting to what I have asked, but your solution fits very well to the loose criteria I have given, and is just what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many "smooth, $S$ shaped functions" that map $0$ to $-1$ and $n$ to $1$. Here is the process of obtaining them:

1. Take $f$, a smooth, $S$ shaped function.
2. Solve the following equations for $a$ and $b$:
   $$af(0) + b = -1\\ a f(n) + b = 1$$
3. The function $g(x) = af(x) + b$ is $S$ shaped, and it maps $0$ to $-1$ and $n$ to $1$. You are done!